# How to set Rails config.time_zone to GMT +6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, utc

When I pop open the rails application.config to set the timezone, I come across an example like this:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

But I would like to try to set my time to something like `GMT+6` unfortunately if I try to use that value I get a Invalid Time Zone error. So what name do I have to use to get GMT+6? I tried looking up the name on [TimeandDate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) but that gave me the same error when I tried to put `Kyrgyzstan Time`

Where exactly is the list of time zones rails uses? Or do I have to use some other format like `+0600` (which doesn't work by the way)

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run

```
rake time:zones:all OFFSET=+6
```

you will get a list of cities

```
* UTC +06:00 *
Almaty
Astana
Dhaka
Ekaterinburg
```

of which the names can be directly used, like

```
config.time_zone = 'Astana'
```